# How to correctly mock event.target by jest with vue test utils?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Hi I'm try test method what load file and call another function what use event.target.closest() for find input parent and add some classes for styled this element. But I'm not have idea how I can pass object event.target for find this parent dom element.

```
<span class="overlay-file">
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="logo-institut" type="file" :placeholder="$t('vnz.addFile')"
                   name="logo" @change="loadFile($event, ['preview', 'logo'])"
                   accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png">
            <span class="container-loaded-file">
              <span class="file-name"></span>
              <span class="remove-loaded-file"
                    @click="removeFile($event)"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </span>
```

> Methods

```
loadFile: function (e, type){
  let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
  this.editImages([type, files])
  this.uploadFileAnimation(e, files[0])
},
 uploadFileAnimation(e, file){
  let parent = e.target.closest('.overlay-file'),
      removeBtn = parent.querySelector('.remove-loaded-file');
  if(removeBtn.classList.contains('remove')){
    removeBtn.classList.remove('remove');
  }
  parent.querySelector('.container-loaded-file').classList.add('loaded');
  removeBtn.classList.add('loading');
  parent.querySelector('.file-name').innerHTML = file.name;
  setTimeout(() => {
    removeBtn.classList.remove('loading');
    removeBtn.classList.add('remove');
  }, 500)
},
```

> test.spec.js

```
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils"
import MyComponent from '../../assets/src/components/MyComponent'

const event = {
target: {
    files: [
        {
            name: 'image.png',
            size: 3576,
            type: 'image/png',
        },
    ],
  },
}

describe('testing component', () => {
test('call upload function',() => {
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
        store, localVue
    })
    const loadFileSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'loadFile')
    const editImagesSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'editImages')
    const uploadFileAnimationSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'uploadFileAnimation')
    wrapper.vm.loadFile(event, ['preview', 'logo'])
    expect(loadFileSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(event, ['preview', 'logo'])
    expect(editImagesSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith([['preview', 'logo'], event.target.files])
    expect(uploadFileAnimationSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(event, event.target.files[0])
  })
})
```

When method uploadFileAnimation was call I have error in test because it's can't find parent element with

```
let parent = e.target.closest('.overlay-file')
```

And I have error `TypeError: e.target.closest is not a function`
If I call trigger 'change' for input e.target passed, but how to append FileList object to event?

```
let input = wrapper.find('#logo-institut')
    await input.trigger('change')
```